# Eclipse Plugin: Get editor state information

Tags: java, eclipse

i have the following problem and am grateful for any help.

I start a batch processing for a file in my plugin and unfortunately I have to make sure that the file is closed in the text editor.

I also have to make sure that other editor references for the same file are closed.

Examples:
"Menu => Window => new Window
"Menu => Editor => Toggle Split Horizontal/Vertical and Clone.

This I have also hopefully managed to do

Here's my code:

```
IWorkbenchWindow[] windows = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows();
        for (IWorkbenchWindow window : windows) {
            IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
            IEditorReference[] editorReferences = page.getEditorReferences();
            for (IEditorReference editorReference : editorReferences) {
                String name = editorReference.getName();
                IEditorPart editorPart = editorReference.getEditor(false);
                if (editorPart instanceof ITextEditor && name != null) {
                    
                    // Here I note down various attributes, e.g. split
                    if (name.equals(memberName)) {
                        MPart mPart = editorPart.getSite().getService(MPart.class);
                        if (mPart != null) {
                            List<String> tags = mPart.getTags();
                            if (tags.contains(IPresentationEngine.SPLIT_HORIZONTAL)) {
                                openConfiguration.setSplitHorizontal();
                            } else if (tags.contains(IPresentationEngine.SPLIT_VERTICAL)) {
                                openConfiguration.setSplitVertical();
                            }
                        }
                        
                        ... // another attributes
                        
                        // close Editor
                        page.closeEditor(editorPart, false);
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now I have the problem that the file is restored in the same state after the batch processing is finished.  For example, if the user has done a "horizontal split" or a "clone" on the previously closed file, this should now be displayed exactly as before. When splitting, for example, also with the same ratio as before.

My solution is that I remember the relevant data before (when closing, see code above) and set it again after opening.

Question: Is this the right approach or is there a more elegant way?

Question: How do I determine the ratio for a split?

Question: How do I recognize a clone reference?  ("Menu => Editor => Clone")

The plugin must run in an RCA that is still based on Eclipse 4.8 and supports the Eclipse 3.x API.

Comment: Why does your batch processing care about a file being open in an editor? It doesn't maintain an open file handle with the OS.

Comment: Thank you for the question.

I am in a rich client application with my plugin that I can only partially control.

The process is as follows:

User opens a file in the editor. The application sets a lock on the opened file on a remote server to prevent competing access to this resource by different users. The batch job on the other hand needs write access to the remote file. So I close the file, start the job and then open the file again. 
The application communicates on the remote server with a daemon that does this.